# JQuery find() with option to ignore specific tags and their children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a jQuery function that will ignore (filter out) specific tags and all their (grand)children when searching, based on their properties.
More specific: I want to find tag which has attribute data-type="a", but only if one of its (grand)parents doesn't have attribute data-type="b".
I guess this doesn't exist and I should write my own javascript code to search. I am inclined to do that but I read that is error prone and not browser compatible?

Comment: filter + parents

Comment: If you have just a little experience, then it should be fairly simple to search and code this yourself. take it 1 step at the time.

Comment: I did code it myself but was curious if more efficient solution was built into jQuery. Simple option to ignore specific tags and their children when using find().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using $.filter() with $.parentsUntil().
Here is general function for someone to use it:

```
// returns found jquery tag(s), jquery object
function FindWithFilterOut($ctlMain, filterIn,

    // any controls that have these properties are filtered out of search and all their children
    // to define multiple filters combined with OR operator use selectors separated with comma, for excample: [data-type='a'],[data-type='c'] 
    filterOut

    ) {
    return $ctlMain.find(filterIn).filter(function (index) {
        var $parentToFilterOut = $(this).parentsUntil($ctlMain, filterOut);
        if ($parentToFilterOut.length > 0)
            return false;
        if ($(this).is(filterOut))
            return false;
        return true;
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tskoda/80s9d61s/3/

Answer (score 3):

jQuery provides a method for doing exactly this kind of thing called `.grep()` (see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) )

```js
var aTypes = $('[data-type="a"]')

aTypes = $.grep(aTypes, function(el, i) {
  return $(el).parents('[data-type="b"]').length === 0
})

console.log(aTypes)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-type="a"></div>
<div data-type="a">
  <div data-type="b"></div>
</div>
<div data-type="b"></div>
<div data-type="b">
 <div data-type="a">Ignore Me</div>
</div>
<div data-type="a">
  <div data-type="a"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var aTypes = $('[data-type="a"]');
var aTypesToKeep = [];
$.each(aTypes, function() {
    var hasBType = $(this).parents().every(function(el) {
        return $(this).attr('data-type') === 'b';
    });
    if (!hasBType) {
        aTypesToKeep.push($(this));
    } 
});
// aTypesToKeep array with jQuery elements of data-type a that don't have parent with data-type b
```